# Display hierarchy selections in a list view in the order of selection

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, hierarchy

I am trying to implement a functionality which will display a list of nodes selected from the TreeNode structure, on the right. 
Something similar to this plunkr I found :  http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1Fr83XHkY0bWd9IzOwuT?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview

In my current method, I am getting the right-side list to be in the same hierarchy order as that on the left.

For eg : Even if I select node "B" before node "A", in the list, it still shows first A and then B (because A is above B in the displayed hierarchy).

Rightside.component.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSelections()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

rightside.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/service/data.service';
import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';

import html from './rightside.component.html';
import css from './rightside.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'rightside-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RightSideComponent implements OnInit {
  selections: string[];
  @Input() treeNode: TreeNode<string>[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getSelections() : TreeNode<string>[] {
    if (typeof(this.treeNode) == "undefined" || (this.treeNode) === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return this.treeNode;
  }

  deselect(item: TreeNode<string>): void {
    if((item.children) !== null) {
      item.children.forEach(element => {
        this.deselect(element);
      });
    }
    item.selected = false;
  }

}
```

productline.component.html:

```
<p>Productlines</p>
<mat-input-container>
    <input #searchInput matInput placeholder="Search for Product Line">
</mat-input-container>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="PLCheck" *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
    <fortune-select
       (dataChanged)="onDataChange($event)"
       [searchTerm]="searchInput.value"
       [currentNode]="tree"
       [singleSelect]="singleSelect"
       [collapsed]="true"></fortune-select>
</div>
<div class="sendToRight">
    <rightside-component
        [treeNode]="selectedProductLine">
    </rightside-component>
</div>
</div>
```

Productline.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as API from '../../shared/api-routes';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/service/data.service';
import { ValidationService } from '../../shared/service/validation.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BasestepComponent } from '../basestep-component/basestep.component';
import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';

import html from './productline.component.html';
import css from './productline.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'productline-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class ProductlineComponent extends BasestepComponent<string> implements OnInit {
  selectedProductLine:    TreeNode<string>[];

  constructor(dataService:DataService, cd:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(dataService, cd);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subject.subscribe((productline) => this.productLineChange(productline));
  }

  public productLineChange(productLine: TreeNode<string>[]):void {
    this.selectedProductLine = productLine;
  }

}
```

Basestep.component.ts:

```
import { Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { castTree, ReportTemplate } from '../report-common';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/service/data.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { ValidationService } from '../../shared/service/validation.service';
import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';

export class BasestepComponent<T> {
  public tree: TreeNode<T>;
  public singleSelect: boolean = false;
  public isDataLoaded: boolean;
  public template: ReportTemplate;
  @Input() templateSubject: Subject<ReportTemplate>;
  @Input() subject: Subject<TreeNode<T>[]>;

  constructor(private dataService:DataService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public onDataChange(event:TreeNode<T>[]):void {
    if (!ValidationService.isNullOrUndefined(this.subject)) {
      this.subject.next(event);
    }
  }


  public markForCheck() {
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }

  public reset() {
    this.tree = null;
    this.isDataLoaded = false;
    this.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

I want the order on the right to be in the order in which the items are selected and not based on the hierarchy. Hence, even if A is above B in the hierarchy, I would want B to be shown and then A based on the selections.

Basically, I would like the selections to be displayed dynamically in the order that they are chosen.

EDIT 1:

Adding code for fortune-select.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from './../dto/TreeNode';

import html from './fortune-select.component.html';
import css from './fortune-select.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'fortune-select',
  template: html,
  styles: [css],
})

export class FortuneSelectComponent<T> {
  @Input() currentNode:  TreeNode<T>;
  @Input() collapsed:    boolean = false;
  @Input() linked:       boolean = true;
  @Input() searchTerm:   string  = '';
  @Input() singleSelect: boolean = false;
  @Output() dataChanged          = new EventEmitter<TreeNode<T>[]>();

  selectedRadioValue:T;

  public checkboxChangedEvent():void {
    let list:TreeNode<T>[];
    this.currentNode.indeterminate = true;

    if (this.linked) {
      list = TreeNode.getTopLevelCheckedNodes(this.currentNode);
    } else {
      list = TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes(this.currentNode);
    }

    this.dataChanged.emit(list);
  }

  public radioChangedEvent(event:TreeNode<T>):void {
    this.dataChanged.emit([event]);
  }
}
```

Is there a way I could maybe store every selection in a list and then display the list? That way, it will show the selections in order. Right now, the entire structure is getting traversed, hence it displays in the tree's order.

Is there a way to do this?